# Ошибка 'NoneType' has object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt5

Я делала задание и у меня возникла проблема с базой данных на Qt5. После запуска файла main4.py появляется окно, в котором я пытаюсь добавить новую продажу(изделие, материал), но появляется ошибка 'NoneType' при нажатии на кнопку "Добавить" или "Редактировать".[image: 1]

Просмотрела весь код, но так и не смогла разобраться. Не могли бы ли Вы помочь мне с этой проблемой?
Заранее благодарю! Весь код содержится на [GitHub](https://github.com/AnnaTonaka/database)

Comment: А при каком действии эта ошибка появляется?

Answer (score 0):

Вы вызываете метод:

```py
# Файл page.py
def newRec(self):
    self.__editForm.new()
```

Он в свою очередь вызывает метод:

```py
# Файл sellseditform.py
def new(self):
    ...
    self._store.setSellDate(code, self.dateEdit.text())
```

Он вызывает метод:

```py
# Файл sellseditform.py
def setSellDate(self, code, value):
    self.__sells.setDate(code, value)
```

Далее вызывается метод:

```py
# Файл sellsListEdit.py
def setDate(self, code, value):
    self.findByCode(code).setDate(value)
```

И наконец вызывается метод:

```py
# Файл generalList.py
def findByCode(self,code):
    for l in self.__list:
        if l.getCode() == code:
            return l
            break
```

И что-то мне подсказывает, что при вызове последнего метода возвращается `None` (так как если вы ничего не находите в списке, то вернется None), у которого просто нет метода `setDate()`, который описан в предпоследнем методе.

Пример ошибки:

```py
def None_func():
    pass

print(None_func().setDate()) # Вернет None и вызовет метод setDate(), которого нет
```

Ошибка:

```py
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setDate'
```

Так что стоит разобраться, что возвращается в вашем случае и смотреть, почему возвращается None.